Local behaviour of the action of a finite subgroup of the automorphism group of a Riemann Surface fixing a point
Consider $(\Sigma,j)$ a closed Riemann surface, and $G \subset Aut(\Sigma,j)$ a finite subgroup that fixes a point $z_0 \in \Sigma$. How can one construct a $G$-invariant neighbourhood $U \ni z_0$ biholomorphic to the disk, $\psi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{D}\subset \mathbb{C}$, such that the $G$-action seen in this coordinate system corresponds to a rational rotation on $\mathbb{D}$? The example I am mostly interested is a pointed hyperbolic Riemann surface, $(\Sigma,j,\Theta)$, where $\Theta \subset \Sigma$ is a finite set and $G=Aut(\Sigma,j,\Theta)$.
I have tried to pass to the universal cover, as the problem is of a local nature, and apply Schwarz lemma to constrain what the action looks like locally. However, I couldn't make this idea work.
As a context: this comes from Chris Wendl notes on J-holomorphic curves (Lemma 4.3.4).

Firstly, note that there is a neighbourhood biholomorphic to a disk by definition of a Riemann surface.
For getting an invariant neighbourhood we can do it by taking an excursion to equivariant topology, by averaging there exists an invariant metric on the surface, then considering the image of the exponential of an open ball centred at the origin of any radius $r$ in the tangent space at $z_0$, gives an invariant open neighbourhood.
Then by taking $r$ sufficiently small, the image is a subset of the open set from the first part, therfore since it is $1$-connected by uniformisation gives an invariant neighbourhood biholomorphic to the disk.
Finally, the holomorphic automorphism group of the complex disk is understood; see any book on Riemann surfaces. Therefore using that elements of $G$ fix the origin and have finite order gives the result.
